# Unity script accurate location access

Tags: unity-game-engine, service, location

I am using a plugin from unity asset store, its online maps, I want to know if anyone else has used it or,
Does anyone know how can we get an accurate location within unity app, 
I used unity's own location service but its not showing me accurate position, its around 100-200 meters varying from my actual location,
I have already checked that my location service is on in device and set to high accuracy mode.
I have also checked all the permissions in manifest file and I did not find any mistake (like course location, fine location, internet, gps hardware etc)
Please suggest if you have any other method which I can use for android.

Comment: If Unity's API is not enough for you, write your own plugin. See [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-plugin-jni-question.100751/) post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the Wifi network on your mobile device. That can lead to errors. You also need to verify if you are initialising the Unity service correctly. You must specify the values in the start function to the accuracy and distance update:

```
Start(float desiredAccuracyInMeters = 10f, float updateDistanceInMeters = 10f)
```

If you choose to declare only Start(), the default values of 10 are used. You must adapt to the results that you want, for instance:

```
Start(3f, 1f)
```